# Linkage of inline functions

Tags: c++, inline, linkage

I have 2 files:

1 is main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int min(int,int);
int abs(int);
int gcd(int,int);

const char *s = "Read Error!!";

int main()
{
  cout << "Enter first Value: ";
  int i;
  cin >> i;
  while(!cin)
  {
    cout << s << endl;
    cin >> i;
  }

  cout << "Enter second Value: ";
  int j;
  cin >> j;
  while(!cin)
  {
    cout << s << endl;
    cin >> j;
  }

  cout << "\nmin: " << min(i,j) << endl;
  i = abs(i);
  j = abs(j);
  cout << "gcd: " << gcd(i,j) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

##2 is gcd.cpp

```
inline int abs(int iobj)
{
  return iobj < 0 ? -iobj : iobj;
}


inline int min(int p1,int p2)
{
  return p1 < p2 ? p1 : p2;
}


int gcd(int v1, int v2)
{
  while(v2)
  {
    int temp = v2;
    v2 = v1 % v2;
    v1 = temp;
  }
  return v1;
}
```

---

Now the problem is when 1 compile the 2 files there is no problem for obvious reasons, however i am getting an error at the time of Linking:
main.cpp:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `min(int, int)'
When i comment line the statement containing the call of min() it works.
Now, why in the world abs() is working, gcd() is working but min() is not???
I am using **g++** in **Linux**.

Comment: Remove the `inline` qualifier from `abs` and `min` in gcd.cpp

Comment: Have you heard of indentation?

Comment: Can you make your question title a bit more descriptive? Pretty much _every_ question in this tag is "regarding a sample CPP project".

Comment: Technically these `inline` functions do have external linkage.  But when you use the `inline` keyword, the function must be defined in every translation unit that uses it.  So `inline` function definitions should be in a header file, not a *.cpp file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abs` "works" because it is in the standard C library as a regular function. Your homebrew `abs` never gets exported from its module because it is `inline`.

The same happens with `min`, but that is not available in the standard library, except as a `template`.

My advice: import `<cstdlib>` and `<algorithm>`, and use `std::abs` and `std::min` instead.

Comment: Well in simple words, does it imply - inline functions have static linkage??

Comment: @Acme: yes. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.6 (The intent of the `inline` keyword is to make functions with **no** linkage, i.e. to have them expanded inline by the compiler rather than the linker.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to learn and want to see your own code called for abs, min, and gcd you could rename them to something like "my_abs" "my_min" and "my_gcd" in both files and then remove the inline keyword from the declarations.

For example:

```
// gcd.cpp

// renamed abs to my_abs to avoid name collision with std library function.
int my_abs(int iobj)
{
    return (iobj<0?-iobj:iobj);
}
```

You have some other options like calling abs/min/gcd using the global scope resoultion operation like "::abs(i).  But if you are new to programming and just trying to get a feel for writing code I think renaming the functions is the simplest approach to get your feet wet.

Answer (score -1):

Abs is probably working because there is an "abs" function in the std. You should add headers and prototype for your code to work : currently, your file 1 ignores everything that exists in your file 2.

Comment: The functions are declared with full prototype in `main.cpp`. `gcd` is properly exported.